# Requests to api on Heroku-hosted NodeJS app not making it to app

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm hosting a NodeJS+Express+Mongoose app on Heroku and have been struggling to understand why some of my GET requests are serving stale data, after repeated changes to resources using the api. The changes only get reflected through the GET call after about half an hour or if I restart the server.

The stale resource data gets returned for requests from multiple clients, my Angular JS webapp as well as curl. So, I'm guessing it isn't something to do with caching on the client.

Based on the logging it looks like the requests aren't even making it to the Express app routes, so I'm guessing there's some kind of caching that's happening on the server. I don't see this behaviour on my local system, so is it something that can be disabled on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you are using Express then your request passes through multiple Express Middleware before actually reaching your app routes. You have to see if there is some error in any of those middleware or there is some validation error for the data which you feed in.

I would suggest you to exhaustively test the data which failed on the heroku app on your local app too.